# Migrating a large SVN repo to git

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have a large SVN repo (around 140GB) that holds many projects and does not follow the svn recommended directory structure. From all this data (it includes binaries, release builds and dependencies), all I really care about  is at an specific path, that actually has a very small history compared to everything else.

All docs I've read so far on SVN-to-Git migration require me to pull the whole SVN repo to Git but this is taking forever, timeouting, going OOM and crashing. Is there any way I can pull only the history for this very specific folder?

Or is there a way I can export the SVN history for this folder alone into a new SVN repo and start the git migration from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass --no-minimize-url, E.G.,:

```
git svn clone <SVN_URL>/your/specific/folder --no-minimize-url --no-metadata folder
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Subversion repository (not just a working copy), I recommend using [svn2git](https://gitorious.org/svn2git/svn2git) because it will be much faster.

Your rules file will resemble

```
create repository specific-folder.git
end repository

# note: trailing slash is important
match /trunk/foo/bar/baz/specific-folder/
  repository specific-folder.git
  branch master
end match

# ignore everything else
match /
end match
```

Then your command will be

```
svn-all-fast-export --identity-map=my-users --rules=specific-folder.rules \
  --stats --add-metadata /full/path/to/subversion/repo
```

Note that your new git repository will contain the *contents* of `specific-folder`.