# How can I convert a large SVN repo to Git?

Tags: git, perl, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to convert several SVN repositories to Git.  Two have gone smoothly.  When I try to convert the next, large-ish one, I get errors from `git svn clone`.  First a bunch of:

```
W: Refspec glob conflict (ref: refs/remotes/origin/tags/Something-Perl):
expected path: something/trunk/tags/Something-Perl
    real path: something/tags/Something-Perl
```

for various "something."  Then one:

```
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/origin/TheName@27584
Use of uninitialized value $args[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git.pm line 1635.
Use of uninitialized value $_[2] in exec at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git.pm line 1661.
fatal: Not a valid object name
ls-tree -z  ./: command returned error: 128
```

Digging, I find line 1635 is

```
return wantarray ? ($fh, join(' ', $cmd, @args)) : $fh;
```

Google found a few instances of errors in `Git.pm` or `SVN.pm` but not this one.  (For reference, I'm using git version 2.19.1 on Linux.)

I really only want two of the directories in that repo so I tried to follow [Migrating a large SVN repo to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411610/migrating-a-large-svn-repo-to-git) but I end up with an empty Git repo:

```
[MyNewRepo]$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git svn fetch retrieves the same Subversion revision multiple times for branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140428/git-svn-fetch-retrieves-the-same-subversion-revision-multiple-times-for-branches)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-svn%5D+Refspec+glob+conflict

Answer (score 1):

If you are only exporting to git you are better of using the KDE svn2git. It's much faster and allows you to create annotated tags.
https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git